# Binary search to upper bound for a real number function

Tags: c++, binary-search

Given an integer X, I need to find the maximum integer N such that N*log(N) <= X.

I am using binary search to compute the answer, but I think the loop is running infinitely for some cases.

This is my binary search function:

```
int f(int X)
{
    int lo=1, hi=time;
    while(lo < hi)
    {
        int mid = lo + hi;
        mid/=2;
        if(mid*log2((double)mid) == X)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        if(mid*log2((double)mid) <= X)
        {
            hi = mid;
        }
        else lo=mid;
    }
    return lo;
}
```

Is my approach correct? If yes, what is the bug in my code? If no, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens if `hi - lo == 1`. In this case `mid` equals `lo`, so `lo = mid` is a no-op and you can end up in an infinite loop.